# A-Frame 4.0 entityEl.getObject3D('mesh'); not returning faces

Tags: javascript, aframe

I'm trying to access the faces of THREE.Mesh through A-Frame.

entityEl.getObject3D('mesh') is returning an object called "Pt" instead of THREE.Mesh. under geometry it doesn't list the faces.

This works in A-Frame V2, but for some reason not in V3 or V4.

Is there a better way to access faces of a THREE.Mesh in A-Frame 4.0?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

0.3.0 and up defaults geometries to be a `BufferGeometry` to save on memory. As a result they are not modifiable in place. Try setting

`geometry="buffer: false"`

on the geometry in order to access the faces and vertices.